watch with piped command executes differently than command itself
What am I doing wrong setting up following watch command? This works:
ls -ltr ~/meteofetcher/data/metar/2024/12 | tail -10 | awk '{ print $9 }' | xargs -I {} grep 'LSZH' {}

But this
watch "ls -ltr ~/meteofetcher/data/metar/2024/12 | tail -10 | awk '{ print $9 }' | xargs -I {} grep 'LSZH' {}"

only lets me watch the following error:
Every 2.0s: ls -ltr ~...  <hostname>: Fri Dec 20 06:27:05 2024

grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.

It's probably something to do with the quotation but I tried to do t he same with single quotes outside and double quotes inside and it still doesn't work.
This produces the same error (and it shouldn't expand the $ afaik)
watch 'ls -ltr ~/meteofetcher/data/metar/2024/12 | tail -10 | awk "{ print $9 }" | xargs -I {} grep "LSZH" {}'

Where did I go wrong?

@ilkkachu Thx, I now switched it to use single quotes around the command, but it still is not right. Putting it in a file is not an option.

Second one, the $9 is protected from your interactive shell but is then evaluated by the shell that watch itself uses to execute the command. You have to escape it as \$9 because it's still inside a double quoted string

In the command
watch "ls -ltr ~/meteofetcher/data/metar/2024/12 | tail -10 | awk '{ print $9 }' | xargs -I {} grep 'LSZH' {}"

... the $9 occurs in a double-quoted string and is therefore expanded by the shell to the ninth command line argument of the shell (likely nothing) before even the watch command is executed.
To fix this, ensure that the dollar sign in $9 is quoted:
watch "ls -ltr ~/meteofetcher/data/metar/2024/12 | tail -10 | awk '{ print \$9 }' | xargs -I {} grep 'LSZH' {}"

You may also delete -10 from the invocation of tail, as that is the default, and change it to head by removing the -r option to ls, and remove the awk completely by removing the -l option to ls:
watch "ls -t ~/meteofetcher/data/metar/2024/12 | head | xargs -I {} grep LSZH {}"

You could alternatively do it like this:
watch 'zsh -c "grep LSZH ~/meteofetcher/data/metar/2024/12/*(.om[1,10])"'

Or to avoid watch running sh to interpret a sh command line that just runs a zsh instance that interprets a zsh command line, cut the sh middle man with the -x option which executes the command directly instead of sh (which we no longer need here as we don't need its piping ability):
watch -x zsh -c 'grep LSZH ~/meteofetcher/data/metar/2024/12/*(.om[1,10])'

With zsh, *(.om[1,10]) would expand to the 10 most recently modified visible regular files in the current directory.  This would enable you to deal with filenames that contain spaces, tabs, newlines, quotes etc., which your original pipeline wouldn't cope with due to awk only outputting the start of those filenames and xargs doing its own interpreting of quoting operators. It also ensures that we don't try to run grep on e.g. directories and avoids running grep if there's no matching file.

a small aside. I saw the construct xargs -I {} cmd {} a few times recently and, while I understand the use of -I {}, the {} being used as the last argument makes me wonder why xargs -n 1 isn't used instead

@Fravadona Embedded unquoted whitespace are handled differently. Compare sending the output of echo 'hello world' as input to xargs -I {} printf '<%s>\n' {} and xargs -n 1 printf '<%s>\n'. You would have to quote the input to have them be the same (echo '"hello world"').

@Fravadona BTW, including quotes in filenames is a great way to break xargs-based scripts that don't use xargs -0.

Well, standard xargs escaping is barely seen as it was deprecated by -0; most people are not aware of it
